# Emulate ssh ProxyCommand on PUTTY

Tags: windows, ssh, proxy, putty

I have an instance at Terminal.com that I want to connect via PUTTy's SSH.

They have a guide saying you could connect to their via a proxy. But I can't really figure things out so easily.

Steps to connect to the VM via SSH are given here: https://www.terminal.com/ssh

I have been able to connect to their system via SSH from an ubuntu box. Although it requires some minor correction in their guide: instead of `yourusername12` in the end while connecting, just use whatever prefix you see in your browser's http bar. If you see  `http://<blablabla>.terminal.com/` then use `<blablabla>.terminal.com` to connect to your instance.

What I have tried till now:

- Created private and public keys via PUTTYgen. Copied this public key into Terminal.com's proxy place. And in my machine's ~/.ssh/authorized_keys. I used SSH2-RSA, 2048 bits.
- Created a SSH connection with that proxy's address `<myusername>@sshterminal.com` to port `2200` and used my private key ppk file in PUTTY's `SSH > Auth` tab. I am successfully able to authenticate, but my window closes within a second after my authentication succeeds. I am assuming my authentication has succeeded as it does not show any error messages, but just tells me: `Using username "<username>". Authenticating with public key "<Key comment>"` and closes my terminal Window with no error messages/output.
- I also tried looking up [this guide](http://monkeyswithbuttons.wordpress.com/2010/10/01/ssh-proxycommand-and-putty/) to emulate ssh ProxyCommand on PUTTY. Unfortunately even this does not work. I went to the windows command prompt and emulated my command. Here's the command I tried: `plink -ssh -P 2200 -i thirumal2.terminal.com.ppk thirumal@sshterminal.com -nc terminal.com:22`. This results in this output: `FATAL ERROR: Server refused to open channel`. I somehow need to still figure out that I should be using `setup_terminal_proxy` instead of `-nc`.

Please help in successfully setup an SSH connection to these guys. Things would be much cheaper  if I can switch to this cloud provider.